# Android: Passing data from child fragment to parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to pass some data from the child fragment to the parent fragment that I will be able to read when I go back to the parent fragment. In detail:

I have a FragmentActivity that calls FragmentParent. From FragmentParent I call FragmentChild like this:

```
FragmentChild fragmentChild = new FragmentChild();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frl_view_container, fragmentChild);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
ctransaction.commit();
```

In FragmentChild I set a string value which I need to pass back to FragmentParent and then I return back to FragmentParent.

```
String result = "OK";
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

What is the best/proper way to read the result string in FragmentParent?

Answer (score 46):

**Android architecture components solution:**

In case you are using Android architecture components, it possible to share data between all `Fragments` of an `Activity` with a `ViewModel`. Ensure `ViewModelProviders` makes use of `Activity` context to create `ViewModels`.

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new MutableLiveData<Item>();

    public void select(Item item) {
        selected.setValue(item);
    }

    public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
}

public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });
    }
}

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getSelected().observe(this, { item ->
           // Update the UI.
        });
    }
}
```

**Non Android architecture components solution:**

You can use [setTargetFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment%28android.app.Fragment,%20int%29) and [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) to achieve this.

Set FragmentParent instance as target fragment on FragmentChild instance i.e.

```
FragmentChild fragmentChild = new FragmentChild();
fragmentChild.setTargetFragment(this, FRAGMENT_CODE);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frl_view_container, fragmentChild);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

In FragmentChild, wherever you are invoking the popBackStack, call onActivityResult on the set target Fragment. Use Bundle to pass on additional data.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(FRAGMENT_KEY, "Ok");
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Back in FragmentParent, override the default onActivityResult method.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == FRAGMENT_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if(data != null) {
           String value = data.getStringExtra(FRAGMENT_KEY);
           if(value != null) {
              Log.v(TAG, "Data passed from Child fragment = " + value);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked but I am unable to update the UI in onActivityResult. Can you help with this?

Comment: @Farooq Arshed: For UI update, you have to refresh your view, like, I am using adapter then I just notify my adapter in onActivityResult. Thats it.

Comment: @Manish Mulimani  once i do this will this call my tabs fragment onStart -> becase i m taking data from server and some of my variables are already intiialized in onStart

Comment: The problem is that `onCreateView` has been calling right after `onActivityResult` and recreate all views in the initial state

Comment: For UI update, I have used  onResume()+static_fields, instead of ChildFragment+listeners, but there are no guaranties about fragment instance, instance can be created again, from nothing but  arguments, sometimes, after gc()  pass. So only SharedPreferences and file system can be 100% reliable.

Comment: is this official way? is there any other solution?

Comment: just want to mention that you have a limit on how much data you can pass with onactivityresult.  You will get a parselable error if it's too large.