# Android: Pass data to parent fragment without overriding

Tags: android, fragment

I have problems to pass my data from my child fragment to my parent fragment.

In my parent fragment

```
public class ParentFragment extends Fragment {
```

I start a child fragment like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ChildFragment fragment = new ChildFragment ();
fragment.setTargetFragment(ParentFragment.this, FRAGMENT_CODE);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.parentfragment, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

to get a team name from a list. By chosing a team in the list of my child fragment the team ID is passed back to the parent fragment:

```
teamId = String.valueOf(id);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("TeamID", teamId);
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), GameActivity.RESULT_OK, intent);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

In the parent fragment I receive data with onActivityResult

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == FRAGMENT_CODE && resultCode == GameActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(data != null) {
                String teamId = data.getStringExtra("TeamID");
                Log.v("ParentFragment", "Data passed from Child fragment = " + teamId);
            }
        }
    }
```

which works fine like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078476/android-passing-data-from-child-fragment-to-parent-fragment).

My problem is by calling the parent fragment onCreate starts again and overrides the teamId. TeamId is then null.

How can I pass the data to the parent fragment without overriding it?

**EDIT:**

This is the "lifecycle" of my teamId:

> Start parent fragment => initialize teamId = Null
>
> ```
>                   v
> ```
>
> Start onCreate => teamId = Null
>
> ```
>                   v
> ```
>
> Start onCreateView => teamId = Null
>
> ```
>                   v
> ```
>
> Start child fragment with setTargetFragment
>
> ```
>                   v
> ```
>
> Choose team in child fragment => teamId = 1   (e.g.)
>
> ```
>                   v
> ```
>
> popBackStack() to parent fragment
>
> ```
>                   v
> ```
>
> Start onActivityResult in parent fragment => teamId = 1
>
> ```
>                   v
> ```
>
> Start onCreateView => teamId = Null

For me it seems that onCreateView "overrides" teamId.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  Why is onCreate() being called again?    Have you implemented onSaveInstanceState() to create the bundle passed to onCreate() when you Activity must be restarted?

Comment: This is how I did it: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { ... sorry, it is onCreateView and not onCreate

Comment: Sorry I messed up with the fragment lifecycle. I have an onCreateView that is started when the fragment returns from the back stack. How can I then pass arguments from the child fragment to the parent fragment without overriding it with my onCreateView?

Comment: onCreateView should not be changing the data contained in the Fragment.  Initialize teamId in onCreate, not onCreateView.

Comment: But I want to reuse teamId in onCreateView because when I come back to the parent fragment from child fragment the team-button-text should change into the team that was chosen in the child fragment. If I initalize teamId in onCreate I cannot access it in onCreateView. Am I right?

Comment: You need to go back to the start and read about Activity life cycle and Fragment life cycle.  Once you understand them, what you are trying to do will be easy.  If you don't understand the life cycles, you will continue to have problems.  Among other things you should NEVER have to call onActivityResult yourself.  Android calls it for you.

Comment: I hope I got the activity life cycle right. I edited my question and added the "life cycle" of my teamId. I hope that helps.