# When is Fragment.onActivityResult called?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment Master A which invokes a (Detail) child fragment B. 
Once the user saves the the details in B, I use the below code as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078476/android-passing-data-from-child-fragment-to-parent-fragment) to return from B to A

```
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(/*Add data to send from B to A to an Intent */);
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

My question is, it seems that A.onActivityResult() is called immediately, even before popBackStack is called in B. And A's onCreateView is called after A.onActivityResult() *Could this cause any problems, for example, when the device is rotated?*

This is not how Activity.onActivityResult behaves. As per the [Android Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29), Activity.onActivityResult is called after the child activity/fragment has exited.

Comment: I donot understand your question. Sine your example code calls `getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(...)` directly this code is called immediately (by your own code).

Comment: Of course, it's paired with `Fragment.startActivityForResult()`

Comment: @k3b, Thanks for responding, I have edited the question to explain the question/concern that I have