# Implement event listener for sending message

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a child fragment class where i click send button. This send text message object. I need to pass this to an interface and then handle it in the main fragment and then give it to my mainactivity. My MainActivity implements this interface. Here is my code.

Interface -

```
public interface OnMessageSendListener {
    void onMessageSendClick(TextMessageWrapper textMessageWrapper);
}
```

Child Fragment -

```
private OnMessageSendListener onMessageSendListener;
if(onMessageSendListener != null)
                onMessageSendListener.onMessageSendClick(textMessageWrapper);
```

MainFragment

```
public void addOnMessageSendListener(OnMessageSendListener onMessageSendListener) {
        this.onMessageSendListener = onMessageSendListener;
    }
```

MainActivity implements interface

Upon OnCreate of MAinActivity, I add listener -

```
messagingFragment.addOnMessageSendListener(this);
```

This is the method to display text message

```
@Override
    public void onMessageSendClick(TextMessageWrapper textMessageWrapper) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message sent: " + textMessageWrapper.body, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Why my interface object onMessageSendListener is null in child fragment. Basically i want to send message from child fragment to main activity.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078476/android-passing-data-from-child-fragment-to-parent-fragment

Comment: Ok but i want to do it using interface