# Android: passing data from one fragment to another with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to send data from a child `Fragment` to the parent `Fragment`. I wrote a code for this, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code so far. The following one is declared in the sender's side.

```
private void sendPINData(String pin) {
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("PINData");
    broadcastIntent.putExtra(Keys.PIN, pin);
    context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Next, the receiver's side (parent `Fragment`)

The following line is in the `onCreateView()` method.

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(localBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("PINData"));
```

And this one is the `BroadcastReceiver` declaration part.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver localBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent != null) {
            pin = intent.getStringExtra(Keys.PIN);
            Toast.makeText(context, pin, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
```

Here's the code in the parent `Fragment` to move to the child `Fragment`.

```
                    PINFragment fragment = new PINFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction mTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    mTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
                    mTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    mTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: please try to debug a little bit. Is the `onReceive()` method triggered?

Comment: it is better approach to register your receiver in onResume() and unregister it in onPause()

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 Thanks for the tip. I reflected that on my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using local broadcast to be received (in App score only) but you are sending broadcast as global .. I think you should use `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Context ctx)` instead of `Context` to send braodcast. see your code updated below:

```
private void sendPINData(String pin) {
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("PINData");
    broadcastIntent.putExtra(Keys.PIN, pin);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

P.S. dont forget to unregister receiver as well

Good luck,'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this didn't work either.

Comment: Is there anything I should change in the receiver's side?

Comment: Are you sure that receiver fragment is alive when you fire the event ?

Comment: I think so. I just added another code that describes moving to the child fragment from the parent fragment.

Comment: If its a parent/child  fragment relationship .. I suggest to use setTargetFragment and onActivityResult to pass data between child fragment back to parent ...see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23079798/2267723.. Local broadcast is used to pass data when you have both fragments attached to Activity i.e. ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

```
private void sendPINData(String pin) {
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("PINData");
    broadcastIntent.putExtra(Keys.PIN, pin);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Try this, please!